# SQL Select on Records that Meet Criteria from Another Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, filtering, aggregate-functions

I've got a very complex query and trying to give a simple example of one of the sub-tables I'm having problems with, if you need more information or context please let me know.

I've posed a CSV file with some sample data here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xdnV0LFZI1dzE5S29QSFhQSmM

We make cakes, and 99% of our cakes are made by us.  The 1% is when we have a cake delivered to us from a subcontractor and we 'Receive' and 'Audit' it.

What I wanted to do was to write something like this:

```
SELECT 
Cake.Cake
Instruction.Cake_Instruction_Key
Steps

FROM
Cake
Join Instruction 
ON  Cake.Cake_Key = Instruction.Cake_Key
JOIN Steps
ON Instruction.Step_Key = Steps.Step_Key

WHERE
MIN(Steps.Step_Key) = 1
```

This fails because you can't have an aggregate in the WHERE clause.

The desired results would be:

```
Cake C 13 Receive
Cake C 14 Audit
Cake D 15 Receive
Cake D 16 Audit
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the HAVING keyword:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

It works more or less the same as the WHERE clause but for aggregate functions after the GROUP BY clause.

Beware however this can be slow. You should try filtering down the number of records as much as possible in the WHERE and even consider using a tempory table to aggregate the data into first.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is the GROUP BY/HAVING clause, so in your case you would need to add something like

```
GROUP BY Cake.Cake, Instruction.Cake_Instruction_Key, Steps
HAVING MIN(Steps.Step_Key) = 1
```